# Import quote and Add product to cart in Magento 2

Tags: php, import, magento2, quote

Creating an external script to import Quotes/Cart (other CMS). My code able to add quote but not creating cart. Need all quoted items to show when user login to their account. I have enabled persistent cart also.

```
   class QuoteMove extends \Magento\Framework\App\Http implements \Magento\Framework\AppInterface 


  public function __construct(
    \Magento\Framework\ObjectManagerInterface $objectManager,
    \Magento\Framework\Event\Manager $eventManager,
    \Magento\Framework\App\AreaList $areaList,
    \Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http $request,
    \Magento\Framework\App\Response\Http $response,
    \Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\ConfigLoaderInterface $config,
    \Magento\Framework\App\State $state,
    \Magento\Framework\Filesystem $fileSystem,
    \Magento\Framework\Registry $registry,
    \Magento\Store\Model\Store $store,
    \Psr\Log\LoggerInterface $logger,
    \Magento\Framework\File\Csv $csvProcessor,
    \Magento\Quote\Model\QuoteFactory $quote,
    \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product $product
)


                $quotes = []; 
                $email = email@domain.com;
                $qty = xxx ;
                $customerId  = xxx ;

                $this->customer = $this->getCustomerByEmail($email);
                    $customerId = $this->customer->getId();

                    $quote = $this->quotes[$customerId];
                    $quote->setCustomerNote(_NOTES_);
                    $quote->setCouponCode(_COUPON_CODE_);

                    $product = $this->_product->load('PRODUCT_ID');  //PRODUCT_ID= xx
                    $params = [];
                    $params['product'] = $productId;
                    $params['qty'] = intval($qty);
                    $options = [];
                    $options[_ATTRIBUTE_] = _VALUE_]   ;
                    $params['super_attribute'] = $options;

                    $config = new \Magento\Framework\DataObject();
                    $config->setItem($params);
                    $quote->addProduct($product,$config);
                    $quote->save();      

                How to Save items in cart now ??
```

So when user login into account able to view items in cart.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is answer I have got it working :

Change  $quote->save();  to   $quote->collectTotals()->save();

after that load quote id and update  updated_at  field date to same as created date. Now login and check your cart. Item will be viewed there.

Answer (score 0):

This is how you need to add product to cart.

```
public function __construct(
 \Magento\Catalog\Model\ProductRepository $productRepository, 
\Magento\Checkout\Model\Cart $cart, 
\Magento\Framework\Data\Form\FormKey $formKey){
            $this->_productRepository = $productRepository;
            $this->_cart = $cart;
            $this->formKey = $formKey;
        }



$params = array(
                'product' => --productID--,
                'qty' => $product->getQty()
            );
    $_product = $this->_productRepository->getById(--productID--);
        $this->_cart->addProduct($_product,$params);
                    $this->_cart->save();
```

Once product is added to the cart, the you can save it to the quote.

Comment: This code is to externally inject cart into customer account when he is offline, so that when customer login he can see the item in cart.   eg: we add to cart item and then logout and login back its available in cart.   IN other way import quote into magento2 from old DB or other DB. Your code doent fit into that condition.